# Spring Boot Swagger API not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, swagger

Here's my `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.0</version>
</dependency>
```

I am using version `1.5.3.RELEASE` of Spring Boot. Here's my swagger config file:

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig {
    @Bean
    public Docket swagger() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
                .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build();
    }
}
```

Here's my `WebSecurityConfig.java`:

```
@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring().antMatchers("/v2/api-docs", "/configuration/ui", "/swagger-resources", "/configuration/security", "/swagger-ui.html", "/webjars/**");
}
```

When I do a get from the endpoint `http://localhost:8080/v2/api-docs` I get my JSON back:

```
{
  "swagger": "2.0",
  "info": {
    "description": "Api Documentation",
    "version": "1.0",
    "title": "Api Documentation",
    "termsOfService": "urn:tos",
    "contact": {},
    "license": {
      "name": "Apache 2.0",
      "url": "http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0"
    }
  },
  "host": "localhost:8080",
  "basePath": "/",
  //ETC
}
```

But when I try to access the UI at `localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html` I get a blank page that looks like this:
[image]

If I click on the page, I get promoted with this
[image]

What am I doing wrong? Is this some sort of spring security issue?

Comment: can you put your code somewhere?

Comment: Try changing the method name from `swagger()` to `api()` in `SwaggerConfig` class.

Comment: Try to use the url: http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html#/ , with **#** symbol at the end

Comment: Show your controllers ?

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64333853/410439

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Added Springfox Swagger-UI and it's not working, what am I missing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46151540/added-springfox-swagger-ui-and-its-not-working-what-am-i-missing)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can suggest API description path to Swagger in application config, using `springfox.documentation.swagger.v2.path` property, e.g.
`springfox.documentation.swagger.v2.path: /rest/docs` in `application.yml`.

I've posted an example [on github](https://github.com/jihor/spring-camel-rest-demo).

Comment: this doesn't really help because I can already access api json from `http://localhost:8080/v2/api-docs`. I just can't get the swagger-ui.html to read from it

Comment: @Richard try changing `"/swagger-resources"` to `"/swagger-resources/**"` in your ignore list for web security, because Swagger goes to `/swagger-resources/configuration/ui` endpoint to get its config.

Comment: @Richard I've updated my github example with security config.

Answer (score 2):

if You use **Version - V3 || io.springfox >= 3.0.0**

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
   <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>
   <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Java code

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2

public class SwaggerConfig {

@Bean
public Docket api() {
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2).select()
            .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("Your Controller package name"))
            .paths(PathSelectors.any()).build();
}
```

}

V3 browser URL -> `http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/#/`
**Run (Must need) : Mvn clean**

Answer (score 0):

Its very likely spring-security is not allowing/preventing your endpoints to be discovered. Try changing your ant matchers to the following and see if that helps. The security/ui configuration endpoints were incorrect.

```
@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring().antMatchers(
        "/v2/api-docs", 
        "/swagger-resources/configuration/ui",     
        "/swagger-resources", 
        "/swagger-resources/configuration/security", 
        "/swagger-ui.html",     
        "/webjars/**");
}
```

Comment: I think it's a spring security issue too but this unfortunately didn't work

Comment: Can you help me on this ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55516559/swagger-api-tag-description-not-coming

Answer (score -1):

change the swagger version to 2.9.2 it will work.

```
   <dependency>
     <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
     <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
     <version>2.9.2</version>
   </dependency>
```