# Swagger API Tag Description Not Coming

Tags: java, swagger, swagger-ui, springfox

I am using below swagger maven depedepncy.

```
    <dependency>
                <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
                <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
                <version>2.8.0</version>
                <scope>compile</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
                <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
                <version>2.8.0</version>
                <scope>compile</scope>
 </dependency>
```

Config

```
public Docket productApi() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("com.it"))
                .build()
                .tags(new Tag("Admin API", "Admin interface to manage users"));
    }
```

Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/kyc")
@Api(tags = {"Admin API"})
@SwaggerDefinition(tags = {
    @Tag(name = "Admin API", description = "Admin interface to manage users")
})
public class KycController
```

But in swagger-ui, description of the Tag is not coming as **Admin interface to manage users**

Comment: There's no "Swagger 2.8.0". Do you mean Springfox 2.8.0?

Comment: @Helen Yes. Updated description

Comment: did you add the following on your config class `@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2`

Comment: @malverndongeni Yes, swagger-ui is opening. Only description in front of Controller/Tag is not coming

Comment: Ok use `@Api(tags ={"Admin Api"},description = "Admin interface to manage users")` .. But you need to downgrade to version 2.6.1 otherwise it will show deprecated warning

Comment: @malverndongeni Thanks for your comment. But it was deprecated long back. I thing in 1.* version